# React function binding in constructor returns undefined

Tags: reactjs

I have a component that looks like

```
class Contact extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {<some state here>};
    this.resetFrom = this.resetFrom.bind(this);
  }
  resetForm() {
    this.setState({<set some state>});
  }
```

and it complains about `TypeError: Cannot read property 'bind' of undefined`. I've read other post about this and checked my syntax but I don't see anything wrong. Why isn't it working?

EDIT: I'm an idiot..... it's indeed the typo.....

Comment: It's a typo, you are using `From` word instead of `Form`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a typo error -

```
 this.resetFrom = this.resetFrom.bind(this); // should be resetForm
```

Answer (score 1):

In your constructor, you call `this.resetFrom`, but your function is named `resetForm`.

F R O M

vs.

F O R M

I think this is just a typo =)